# Calculating the volume of a solid in the first octant.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am asked to verify the divergence theorem for a vector field in the region of the first octant limited by $x=2$ and $y^2+z^2=9$, so I need to calculate the volume of this solid. However I don't know how to delimitate the bounds of the triple integral, of course $0\leq x \leq 2$, $-\sqrt{9-z^2}\leq y\leq \sqrt{9-z^2}$  but I don't know how to follow.

Comment: If you need only the volume, it's the volume of a quarter of a cylinder, and you don't need any calculus. If you're doing a triple integral, I would recommend using cylindrical coordinates (with polar coordinates in the $yz$-plane and $x$ as the extra variable). You've provided hardly any details, so it's hard to give good advice.

Comment: If it is in the first octant also $\;x\ge0\;$ .

Answer (score 1):

As Ted Shifrin said this solid is a quarter of a cylinder.  $y^2+ z^2= 9$ is the cylinder with axis along the x-axis and radius 3.  Requiring that x= 2 and x= 0 (since this is in the first octant) gives a cylinder with volume $\pi(3^2)(2)= 18\pi$.  Since this is in the first quadrant, the volume is $\frac{18\pi}{4}= \frac{9}{2}\pi$.

To do the volume in cylindrical coordinates, I would swap the x and z coordinates: The region is that portion of the cylinder $x^2+ y^2= 9$ in the first quadrant from z= 0 to z= 2.  That would be $\int_0^2\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^3 rdrd\theta dz$.